# Get value nested within a number of classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the value in the `pickup-address` class, but with little success. This is my code so far. What am I doing wrong?

JS

```
var pickupAddress = $('.timeline-item.active-item > .timeline-status > .pickup-address').val();
alert(pickupAddress);
```

HTML

```
<div class="timeline-item active-item" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/jsa/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-rounded profile">
    <div class="timeline-status" style="width: 185px;"><strong>Stephen
    </strong>
        <br><span class="pickup-address">Whaddon</span> — <span class="dropoff-address">Bancroft</span>
        <br><span class="timeline-substatus grey-status waypoints">Via Lathbury</span>
        <br><span class="timeline-substatus grey-status remaining-seats">3 places remaining</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.val` because `pickup-address` is not `input` field

```
var pickupAddress = $('.timeline-item.active-item > .timeline-status > .pickup-address').text();
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/zijuci/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

Use text() instead of val(). I think val() works only with inputs elements.